# Magento does not create cache, reports and logs

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, php-7

I noticed that my magento onlineshop does not create any files in `var/cache`, `var/report` and it does not report anything to the logfiles in `var/log`.

The var directory has the permissions `drwxrwxr-x` and the user and group are set correctly

Logging is enabled:

[image]

What is going on?

Comment: What permissions do you applied to var dir

Comment: @YlgenGuxholli see my updated question

Comment: @RakeshDonga, yes logging is enabled in backend.

Comment: Glad you solved that :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I changed the permission of the folder `var` to 777 temporarily. Then because I had error reporting and developer mode turned on in the index.php, I got an error saying that the `cache` dir is not writable.

So it was obvious that the user or group were not correct. It turned out that I had to change the group `wwwrun` to `www`.

So I executed `chown -R myuser:www *` in my magento root.